# What would be the way to say "Have a good Hajj" to someone who is about to travel to Saudi Arabia for their Hajj?

Tags: arabic, hajj, language

I have a Muslim friend who is going for Hajj and I want to wish something like:
"I wish you good luck for your Hajj" or "best wishes for your Hajj".

I have never heard someone say "Hajj Mubarak". Is there a phrase that Muslims use for this type of thing?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand,"Hajj Mubarak" is said after completing the Hajj as it is a congratulatory message.

I couldn't find any reference but I usually greet my friends going on Hajj by saying:

> “تقبل الله (taqabbal Allah)”

It means : May Allah accept it from you.

***Also we should ask them to make dua for us during Hajj***  :-)

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed. Is Taqabbal Allah said before going to Hajj? And is that used *only* for Hajj, or for other things too? I was looking for something specific to Hajj. Also, what does "make dua for us" mean ?

Comment: That is a generic prayer wishing that Allah accepts the good deeds to be performed or already performed by the person being addressed. With respect to your question on 'make dua for us' I'd recommend you ask it as a separate question as there are a lot of Hadith on the subject that you will receive as answers and inshallah they will increase knowledge. But in short, it is believed that a person whose Hajj is accepted by Allah is a like a new born baby (sinless) and any dua he/she would have made during Hajj would be accepted by Allah.